# Why is animation triggered on load

Tags: qt, qml, qt5

When the window opens you can see the Rectangle sliding out. I set the `y` property to the parent height so it should be initially outside of the window why is this being animated?
My guess it's because of the `parent:height`. Maybe because `parent.height` is not available at loading time and it's initially set to 0?

I have following example to reproduce:

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Rectangle {
        id: test;
        y: parent.height;
        states: [
            State {
                name: "slideOut"
                PropertyChanges{
                    target: test;
                    y: parent.height;
                }
            },
            State {
                name: "slideIn"
                PropertyChanges{
                    target: test;
                    y: 0;

                }
            }
        ]
        Behavior on y {
            NumberAnimation {
                duration: 500;
            }
        }
        color: "red";
        width: parent.width;
        height: parent.height;

    }

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent;
        onClicked: {
            if(test.state == "slideIn") {
                test.state = "slideOut";
            } else {
                test.state = "slideIn";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your guess sounds spot on to me.

You should use [transitions](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-transition.html) with states instead:

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Rectangle {
        id: test
        y: parent.height
        width: parent.width
        height: parent.height
        color: "red"

        states: [
            State {
                name: "slideOut"
                PropertyChanges {
                    target: test
                    y: parent.height
                }
            },
            State {
                name: "slideIn"
                PropertyChanges {
                    target: test
                    y: 0
                }
            }
        ]
        transitions: [
            Transition {
                NumberAnimation {
                    property: "y"
                    duration: 500
                }
            }
        ]
    }

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: {
            if (test.state == "slideIn") {
                test.state = "slideOut"
            } else {
                test.state = "slideIn"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Another solution could be to use the [enabled](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-behavior.html#enabled-prop) property of Behavior to only run the animation when the window is ready. I'm not sure which property you'd base it on though. Some ideas:

- `enabled: window.height > 0`
- `enabled: window.active`

Comment: Thanks transitions works much better. I am just curious where this behavior comes from

Comment: In my experience it comes from exactly what you said: the window height starts off at 0 and at some point (when the window is properly exposed or activated or whatever) it becomes non-zero. This behaviour is not specific to windows getting their eventual geometries though; I've run into the same problem with the "Behavior on" syntax a few times (e.g. resizing). "Behavior on" is useful in certain situations: namely those where you have control over the changes in value. When you don't have control, it will run when you don't want it to. You could try to selectively enable it.. will update post.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation I think I stick to the transition in my case transition is the more appropriate/better solution